# How to store the retrieved file in lambda tmp storage in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I retrieved the image and base64 converted the image to decode-base64 -image and and I tried to store it in tmp file of lambda function and I get an error

> errorMessage": "EROFS: read-only file system, open '/var/task/sample.jpg'

I am unable to change directory to tmp and store in it

code

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
//*/ get reference to S3 client 
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
const fs = require('fs');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
              var params = {
              "Bucket": "bucketname",
              "Key": "object"  
            
            };
        
  function decodeBase64Image(dataString) {
      var matches = dataString.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/),
      response = {};
      if (matches.length !== 3) {
      return new Error('Invalid input string');
    }
        
      response.type = matches[1];
      response.data = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');
      return response;
    }
        
    s3.getObject(params, function(err, data){
        if(err) {
          callback(err, null);
          console.log("upto here");
        } 
        else
        {    console.log("upto here");
              let image = new Buffer(data.Body).toString('base64');
              console.log(image);
            //  var svimg = decodeBase64Image(image);
              image = "data:"+data.ContentType+";base64,"+image;
              fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+ '/sample.jpg', image );
          let response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            'Content-Type': data.ContentType
            },
        "body":image,
        "isBase64Encoded": true
    };
        callback(null, response);
    }
    });
    
};
```

Comment: Why are you unable to change the directory to /tmp? Without posting your code, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: i just added the code to pls make a review in it and give me some solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can not store any files permanently in lambda. You can use an S3 bucket.
İf you want to save anyway, use the `/tmp/sample.jpg` path.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but I agree with the downvote. There are three sentences in this answer, and the first two are an answer to a question nobody asked.